# Java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found

Tags: jmeter, exception

As i am connecting to JDBC with jmeter im getting the error even though my **url, jdbc driver class, username and password** is provided correctly.

Below is the error :

> 2014/04/21 18:59:09 WARN  -
>   jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement: Could not return
>   Connection java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.46:1522:dev10g    at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)  at
>   org.apache.avalon.excalibur.datasource.JdbcConnectionFactory.newInstance(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.avalon.excalibur.pool.ResourceLimitingPool.newPoolable(ResourceLimitingPool.java:672)
>     at
>   org.apache.avalon.excalibur.pool.ValidatedResourceLimitingPool.newPoolable(ValidatedResourceLimitingPool.java:178)
>     at
>   org.apache.avalon.excalibur.datasource.ResourceLimitingJdbcConnectionPool.newPoolable(ResourceLimitingJdbcConnectionPool.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.avalon.excalibur.pool.ResourceLimitingPool.get(ResourceLimitingPool.java:402)
>     at
>   org.apache.avalon.excalibur.pool.ValidatedResourceLimitingPool.get(ValidatedResourceLimitingPool.java:130)
>     at
>   org.apache.avalon.excalibur.datasource.ResourceLimitingJdbcDataSource.getConnection(ResourceLimitingJdbcDataSource.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement$DataSourceComponentImpl.getConnection(DataSourceElement.java:286)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.getConnection(DataSourceElement.java:146)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.sampler.JDBCSampler.sample(JDBCSampler.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:428)
>     at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMeter doesn't come with any JDBC driver shipped. Looking into stacktrace I can see that you're using Oracle and presumably 10g version. You need to download [Oracle JDBC driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html) (or better fetch it from ORACLE_HOME/jdbc/lib, you'll need `ojdbc6.jar` as it matches Java 6 which is required for the latest JMeter) and drop it to `/lib` folder of your JMeter installation.

Also don't forget to properly set up [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration)

See [Using JDBC Sampler in JMeter](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65143-using-jdbc-sampler-in-jmeter-2-6) guide for more useful tips.

Comment: @ Dmitri T thanks, i will make use of the website and say.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle 10g or 11c please add ojdbc7.jar to your Jmeter/lib folder. Close your Jmeter and open it again. Worked for me.